# foorloop.counter always reset its value when move to anothe rpage?

Tags: python, django

I have a list and for serial no I am using `{{ foorloop.counter }}` but it always resets to 1 when we move on to the next page.

my view :-

```python
def university_list(request):
    totalCount = None
    search_by_list = filterConfig.university_filter
    object_name = "university"
    university_status = "universityStatus"
    page_size = utility.setting_pagination(request.GET.get('page_size'))
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    select_option_value = request.GET.get('type')
    search_value = request.GET.get("q")
    university_all_list = Universities.objects.using("cms").order_by('-modifiedAt').all()

    if (
            select_option_value is not None and
            select_option_value != '' and
            search_value is not None and
            search_value != ''
    ):
        search_filter = utility.create_search_filter_query_by_filter_list_key(search_by_list, select_option_value)
        university_all_list = university_all_list.filter(**{search_filter: search_value})
        totalCount = university_all_list.filter(**{search_filter: search_value}).count()
    university_all_list = utility.global_pagination(university_all_list, page, page_size)

    return render(
        request, 'templates/university/university_list.html',
        {
            'data_list': university_all_list,
            'object_name': object_name,
            'search_by_list': search_by_list,
            'select_option_value': select_option_value,
            'page_size': page_size,
            'page': page,
            'totalCount': totalCount,
            'university_status':university_status
        })
```

This is my view as you can see I am getting `page` and `page_size` so I mathematically come to conclusion how to do it but don't know how to do this on templates.

```python
for x in range(1,page_size+1):
    if page:
        serial_no = page_size*(page-1)+x
    else:
        serial_no = x
    print serial_no
```

It shows an error `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'int'`
and I am not that hopeful that it will work. Can someone suggest some other way out to this?

Comment: You should have a look at the Django documentation for handling the pagination : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view, pagination should be easier :) And your code is not quite easy to read, please change the indentation so it fit on stackoverflow, thx.

Comment: The for loop counter does indeed reset when moving to a different page. If you want to keep counting, you need to keep into account the current page (times the items per page) and add the number of interations for that page.

Comment: You can pass the current start counter to the template and then add forloop.counter to it.

Comment: It will also restart if you start a different loop in the same template or if you use a nested loop. It counts the iterations in the current loop, similar to how `enumerate()` works. It's not some kind of global value that carries across loops.

Comment: "but it always resets to 1 when we move on to the next page." I should hope so because that's how it's supposed to work.